# different column name from table but same DTO

Tags: sql, refactoring, multiple-columns

Hi I have this code where I retrieve data from the stored proc. At the moment it works fine for two methods as the column returned from the stored proc are the same but now the problem is that I have to add a third method say method GetDataC(The data is exactly the same...however someone who wrote the proc is returned different name of the columns) for eg for AA i  have _AA for BB i have BBsometext. I dont want to duplicate the GetSomeData method.

```
    public IList<SomeData> GetDataA(Query q)
    {
        var ds = someService.GetA(q);
        return GetSomeData(ds);
    }

    public IList<SomeData> GetDataB(Query q)
    {
        var ds = someService.GetB(q);
        return GetSomeData(ds);
    }

    private IList<SomeData> GetSomeData(DataSet ds)
    {
        IList<SomeData> SomeData = new List<SomeData>();
        var helper = new DataSetHelper(ds);
        if (helper.HasRows())
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in helper.GetRows())
            {
                SomeData.Add(new SomeData
                {                       
                    AA = helper.GetNullableDouble(row, "AA"),
                    BB = helper.GetNullableDouble(row, "BB"),
                    CC = helper.GetNullableDouble(row, "CC"),
                    EE = helper.GetNullableInt(row, "DD"),
                    FF = helper.GetNullableDouble(row, "EE"),
                    GG = helper.GetNullableDouble(row, "FF"),                                   
                });
            }
        }
        return someData;
    }     
}
```

is there a way to do this ?